# MySQL 5.7 stopped working on mac El Capitan

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-elcapitan

I upgraded the mysql from 5.5 to 5.7. I was working very well.
Today when I turned on my mac the mysql was not working and I can't start.
I tried to start by LaunchDaemon on system preferences but nothing happens and I tried by this command on terminal:

```
sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

When I run this command I receive this message:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist: service already loaded
```

but not work...

**edit:** I have no Idea why, but I restarted my mac and now it's working

Comment: Have you tried looking into any log files? Perhaps starting the mysql daemon "by hand" instead of via launchd and see what it says?

Comment: after upgrading, don't forget to run `mysql_upgrade` and restart the service.  I completely forgot and wondered why external tools failed to connect.

Answer (score 1):

first unload

sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist

(replaced from onload )

then

sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but my system automatically renamed the MySQL directory.

I identified that the usr/local/mysql/ directory was now called usr/local/mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64/

What I did that solved the problem, was to create a symbolic link

{sudo ln -s mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64 mysql}
I rebooted my mac, and everything worked correctly.

you will probably need to identify the new directory name with the command

{ls usr/local}